# kill subprocesses using bash script

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-12.04

I want to run a python program 1000 times. If successful it returns output in about 90 seconds, else continue to run may be for 4 hours.
I want to run a bash script that will run the python program in a loop in such a way that it waits 100 seconds for the script to terminate successfully else kill it.

It must not kill the next instance of the program which may become successful.

I am working in Ubuntu 12.04 lts.

```
for i in {1..1000..1}
do
    ./myprocess.py
    sleep 100
done

#And then what........?
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`timeout`](http://man.cx/timeout) command. Your situation is the exact case, this command is designed for.

```
timeout 100 ./myprocess.py
```

Comment: In case of timeout (forcefully terminated) does it returns anything?

Comment: The exit status for `timeout` is described explicitly in the documentation you were just linked to.

Comment: Thanks. But i want to catch the instances when a timeout has occur. For example x=$(timeout 4m ./test) like this